# Javascript subscribe AngularFire2

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using `Ionic2/Angular2`, and need to call a function with the parameter `authData`, as seen below.

```
  public auth: FirebaseAuth

   this.auth.subscribe((authData: FirebaseAuthState) => {
     if (authData) {
       let promise: Promise<any> = this.utilityService.login(this.personModel, authData.auth, this.nav, this.auth, this.fireAuth, false);
     }
   });
```

My problem is, because I am subscribing to the `FirebaseAuth`, the `utilityService.login` function gets called multiple times.

**Question**

How do I structure this code, so that the `utilityService.login` function only gets called once?

Thank youi

Answer (score 0):

Solution

No need to `subscribe`. The user can be obtained as follows.

```
          let promise: Promise<any> = this.utilityService.login(this.personModel, this.auth.getAuth().auth, this.nav, this.auth, this.fireAuth, false);
```

Comment: Problem with this is: `auth.js:104 WARNING: the getAuth() API has changed behavior since adding support for Firebase 3.
    This will return null for the initial value when the page loads, even if the user is actually logged in.
    Please observe the actual authState asynchronously by subscribing to the auth service: af.auth.subscribe().
    The getAuth method will be removed in future releases`